# Text filed edit in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a text field with some data (name of the user) from the DB. I should allow the user to edit his name and then save in the DB.

My problem is am unable to edit the text field. This is my code:

```
var nameController = TextEditingController();

TextFormField(
                
    controller: nameController=TextEditingController(text:snapshot.data[index].name,),                                         
                      onChanged: (name){
                        
                        setState(() {
                          nameController.text = name;
                        });
                      },
                    

)
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to edit text

when user types, the text will appear automatically. 
You don't need to call `setState` or `TextEditingController.text` to set the text again.

Example:

```
    TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'Enter your username'
  ),
);
```

### How to save to Db when text changes.

There are several options.

1. Use another button, say 'save' to save the text. If that is the case, then use `textEditingController.text` vale to save to the DB
2. If you want to save the data when the text changes, you may use the
   `onChanged: (name)` callback. But please note that, this callback will
   get called too frequent when the user types text and doing DB
   operation on each text change event may not be a good idea. But yes, you can use the powerful APIs of RxDart to debounce the events and find out when user stops typing and use that value to save to the DB.

### How to read text from TextField?

[This](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/retrieve-input) official doc explains it in detail with some good examples.

### How to assign initial value to the TextField?

You can use the `TextEditingController` for this purpose.

```
final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();
    @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _Controller.text = "Your Text";
    }
```

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Initial value of the textfield is getting from DB. If the user wish to edit his name then updated name should be stored in the DB. I have called save function to do so. However, my textfiled value is getting refreshing and going to the initial value  when i click Save button.

Comment: @raj on the init state method, you can initialize the controller with the initial value. Also, on save method, use the  same controller object to read the current value, eg: controller. text. Could you please explain where exactly you face difficulty?

Comment: after changing the textfield value, when i click the done button in the keyboard it is showing the previous value only (before changing which i retrieved from DB )